# How to debug an app on iPhone without internet

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, wireless

I'm using Xcode 10.1, and I don't have a checkbox whether I want to connect through network or not on my device page (which was there in Xcode 9 and Xcode 10 beta). Search "connect via network xcode" on google images if you don't know what I mean.

However, I must debug the offline flow of my app (which is written in React-Native btw). Not just no-internet-connection, but turning off wifi and mobile-data, which will trigger a status change. By using the developer settings of the iPhone, I can make every call fail (100% loss), but cannot change the internet-status of the phone.

So I want the debugger to stay connected and either be able to:

- debug the old-school way through the cable (if I turn off internet now, I get a red error screen and nothing is possible anymore), so I can disable wifi and mobile-data,
- or simulating that status change on the phone.

Btw, I cannot use a simulator, since the app requires Bluetooth.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

The checkbox is not there for older iPhone devices. With iPhone 7s, I do see the checkbox "connect via network". But enabling or disabling does not change the fact that your iPhone needs internet to debug. If I disable internet on the phone I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Seems like your only option is to use a logging tool (for example, [SwiftyBeaver](https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver)) and possibly a crash inspector (like [KSCrash](https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash)).

Comment: Possibly [network link conditioner](https://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) ? Don't quite understand why you can't just debug via a cable though.

Comment: @shim The moment I turn internet off, the app crashes, because the code is served over wifi... This is a new feature introduced in Xcode 9, where you still had the option to either use the cable or wifi... But in Xcode 10.1, this option seems to be removed

Comment: Xcode 10 definitely installs and debugs via the Lightning cable

Comment: I am on Xcode 10.2.1 and I can see the "Connect via network" checkbox in Devices (the device must be plugged in for it to show the checkbox). But if it's a React Native app are you not running it through Expo?

Comment: I'm not running through Expo, I do have a cable, but I don't see the checkbox... I'll upgrade Xcode to 10.2 to see if the checkbox is back

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the problem. We are testing on a iPhone5, which is no longer officially supported by Apple. Which means that Apple has decided to cut features for iPhone5 so you would buy a new one (wonderful strategy =/). Hence debugging with a cable is no longer supported on iPhone5.

We tested with a iPhone6 from a colleague, and everything works fine.

Edit:
Altough the checkbox is there, and I can disable wifi for connection... The moment I turn off internet on the phone, the app crashes and says: "Runtime is not ready for debugging: make sure packager runtime is running"... so no solution yet...